# How to use PL/SQL with pure C#?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, plsql

I elaborated this little piece of code to get started with my baby steps. The connection is good. Simple `OdbcDataReader` selects are working fine. But I can't test any PL/SQL functions. How does it work ? Do I need to install something extra or do I do something wrong ?

[some inspiration](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18593/Processing-with-C-and-Oracle-PL-SQL)

```
using System;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "dsn=TEST;uid=read;pwd=___";
            OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();

            try
            {
                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("begin end;", con);
                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
            }

            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The PL/SQL program is obviously:

```
begin
end;
```

Error message is the following:

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]OR
A-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

    begin declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise
    return select update while <an identifier>
    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
    close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
    savepoint set sql execute commit forall
    <a single-quoted SQL string>
```

Comment: What pl/sql function were you attempting to test?

Comment: @DanBracuk: `begin end;`. It is in the question.

Comment: If that's a function, what is it supposed to do?

Comment: @DanBracuk This here wasn't supposed to do anything. It's the baby-steps-method of learning something new. Please check the 1st paragraph of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your error is on the PL/SQL side instead of the c# code side.

This is invalid, since between `begin` and `end` a statement is expected:

```
begin end;
```

This isn't invalid, since it contains a statement, although it is `null;`:

```
begin null; end;
```